# MFC C++ CView slow refresh rate in debugging

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, mfc

Problem: In MFC, my tables and graphs (In views) refresh very fast in release mode, and really slow in debug mode, **until** I start repopulating data (We run tests that gather large data sets (10,000 pts)).

I'm using the CView class in 2 different ways.

1. I draw the table and graph manually using code we've created.
2. I use the TableGridView written by the toolkit: http://www.codejock.com/products/toolkitpro/ which has it's own GridView class which is derived from CView.

Both ways, show a very slow refresh rate, until I start re-populating the graphs, and tables with large data sets.

I cannot determine what is causing the slow refresh rate. I went into release mode, and turned off code optimization, and that did not recreate the slow refresh rate of debug mode.

Question: Any tips on how I should go narrow down the cause of this behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) explains how to find out, where time is spent. If you are dealing with lots of small memory allocations, I would guess the [debug heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) to make up for the majority of the difference.

Comment: I know that if I do a TRACE inside a loop (for debug purposes), that can GREATLY slow down my UI when the loop is "long" (e.g. 10,000 TRACEs).

Comment: It's quite possible that you perform some computation-heavy operations in your OnDraw() function. This type of code runs a lot faster if compiled without debug info. Library, system or I/O operations are not affected, eg StretchBlt() is considered a "slow" function, because it resizes the bitmap to be transferred, but compiling the app w/ debug options won't make it any slower. I would say check whether you perform calculations in the OnDtraw() function, which could be moved somewhere else, eg when data are changed (eg in OnUpdate()) and this warrants a recalc, and not on every paint request.

Comment: Thanks guys, your tips steered me in the right direction, and I eventually found the function that helped with performance was _CrtSetDbgFlag().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue, and wanted to share it. In the #ifdef _DEBUG section of our code, we were setting flags using _CrtSetDbgFlag()
to do additional memory checks on the heap. This was slowing down the software considerably.

After setting

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_CHECK_DEFAULT_DF);
```

my code ran very quickly in Debug mode